# (Transact-SQL) DATEDIFF and leap years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with DATEDIFF function.

My date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

`@START_DATE = 01/02/2004`
`@END_DATE = 29/01/2014`

The query `(DATEDIFF(DAY,@START_DATE,@END_DATE) / 365)` return `10`, but the number of correct years is `9`. This happens because my query does not consider leap years.

What I can do to keep an accurate count?
Thanks.

Comment: There are closer to 365.25 days in a year, so you shouldn't expect your arithmetic to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following logic does what you want:

```
   datediff(year,
            @START_DATE - datepart(dayofyear, @START_DATE) + 1,
            @END_DATE - datepart(dayofyear, @START_DATE) + 1
           ) as d2
```

Note:  This treats that dates as `datetime`, because arithmetic is easier to express.  You can also write this as:

```
   datediff(year,
            dateadd(day, - datepart(dayofyear, @START_DATE) + 1, @START_DATE),
            dateadd(day, - datepart(dayofyear, @START_DATE) + 1, @END_DATE)
           ) as d2
```

The following query is a demonstration:

```
select datediff(year,
                startdate - datepart(dayofyear, startdate) + 1,
                enddate - datepart(dayofyear, startdate) + 1
               ) as d2
from (select cast('2004-02-01' as datetime) as startdate,
             cast('2014-01-31' as datetime) as enddate
      union all
      select cast('2004-02-01' as datetime) as startdate,
             cast('2014-02-01' as datetime) as enddate

     ) t
```

Comment: It works! :D But I have one question: why adding +1?

Comment: @Andryx93 . . . 2014-01-05 is the fifth day of the year.  If you subtract 5, you get 2013-12-31.  The idea is to normalize the dates to the beginning of the year for the comparison.

Comment: year(@START_DATE - datepart(dayofyear, @START_DATE) + 1) is kind of useless. It will still be the same year as year(@START_DATE) as far as i can tell

Comment: @t-clausen.dk . . . That is true.  But I think about this logically where the time period is being shifted uniformly, so that start date is at the beginning of the year.  I find that easier to follow than just shifting the end date.

Answer (score 2):

Technically there would be 365.242 days in a year, when accounting for leap years so:

```
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE) / 365.242)
```

Should be more correct.

Test:

```
SELECT  FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '1980-01-16','2015-01-15') / 365.242),
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '1980-01-16','2015-01-16') / 365.242)
```

ResultSet:

```
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
34                                      35
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to address that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getYears] 
(
    @START_DATE datetime,
    @END_DATE datetime
)  
RETURNS int
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @yrs int
    SET @yrs =DATEDIFF(year,@START_DATE,@END_DATE)
    IF (@END_DATE < DATEADD(year, @yrs, @START_DATE)) 
       SET @yrs = @yrs -1
    RETURN @yrs
END
```

Also check [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2688/work-around-for-calculating-age-using-the-sql-server-datediff-function/)

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of leap days in end_date  Deduct number of leap days in start_date.  Deduct the answer from your DATEDIFF.

```
DECLARE
    @START_DATE DATETIME = '2004-02-01',
    @END_DATE DATETIME = '2014-01-29'

SELECT (
        DATEDIFF(DAY,@START_DATE,@END_DATE)
            - (
                (CONVERT(INT,@END_DATE - 58) / 1461) 
                -
                (CONVERT(INT,@START_DATE - 58) / 1461)
            )
        ) / 365
```

-58 to ignore Jan and Feb 1900

/ 1461 being the number of days between leap years